# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 at xxx while calculating an average of integer numbers

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

Simple average program I am trying to make but

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0  at average.main(average.java:8)
```

The eighth line (the rest is below) is

```
int i1 = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
```

Full code below:

```
public class average {

    public static void main (String args[]) {

        int sum = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i <= args.length; i++) {
                int i1 = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
                sum = i1 + sum;
        }

        int average = sum / (args.length - 1);
        System.out.println(average);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try replacing `i >= args.length` with `i < args.length`

Comment: What arguments are you passing when you get this error?

Comment: i am actually trying to run it in terminal and when I do I get this error. I don't even get to type numbers yet

Comment: @JackStotler Please have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You want to change

```
for(int i = 0; i <= args.length; i++)
```

to

```
for(int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
```

Suppose args contains 2 data, then `args.length` will return 2 right ?

So, `for(int i = 0; i <= args.length; i++)` will iterate 3 times (i = 0, i = 1, and i = 2 as you allowed i to be equals to args.length).

However, args[2] does not exist, as there is only 2 values (args[0] and args[1]).

Also, note that `sum = i1 + sum;` can be simplified to `sum += i1`.

You could even shorten more your loop :

```
for(String s : args)
    sum += Integer.parseInt(s);
```

I would personally prefer this syntax, and you are sure to not iterate over bounds using it :).

Comment: Just as a note, that form of for-each is typically used more for accessing data than manipulating/setting it (where for arrays the original syntax is what you want).